# Google analytics report by demographics by date

Tags: google-analytics, demographics

Google analytics report by demographics by date doesn't shows data for all age groups, while if I remove date it shows all age groups in GA demographics report, don't understand this behavior,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from inferring the demographics or interests of individual users**. When a report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report. For example, if there are fewer than N instances of Gender=male in a report, then data for the male value may be withheld.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en

In conclusion, **it is not always possible to obtain demographic data with granular detail in Google Analytics reports**. This is due to both user privacy issues and the fact that these data, **based on a portion of total users**, are found in the database of the analysis platform within dedicated tables and with pre-aggregated values.